# Vaadin Upload function

Tags: java, file, upload, vaadin

I'm interested in having a button which takes a pic from the user's computer and uploads it on my server.

I managed to solve the server uploading part, but I'm having difficulties in handling the path from the user computer. Vaadin Upload does not provide me full path, but I want it to be dynamic. Looking at the documentation, they use some temp location, but I don't know how to implement that.

```
public OutputStream receiveUpload(String filename,
                                      String mimeType) {
        // Create upload stream
        FileOutputStream fos = null; // Stream to write to
        try {
            // Open the file for writing.
            file = new File("/tmp/uploads/" + filename);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            new Notification("Could not open file<br/>",
                             e.getMessage(),
                             Notification.Type.ERROR_MESSAGE)
                .show(Page.getCurrent());
            return null;
        }
        return fos; // Return the output stream to write to
    }
```

I'm expecting that when the File Chooser closes, I get some kind of file path or handler so I can put it on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `filename` argument you will have the name of uploaded file.
The path of the file however is not sent to the server, this is one of the restrictions of web applications / web browsers.

With the code you use, you will have a copy of the uploaded file on your server in the tmp folder.

There is no way to directly access files on client computers through the web browser.

Comment: Solved it, it was trying to upload to /tmp/uploads but didn't have permissions